# Magento 2 show product to phtml

Tags: magento-2.1, product, php

I am new to magento. I am using magento 2, and I already create a new module to test for product output.

Block :

```
 public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
```

show.phtml :

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData('type_id'));
}
```

It's only show the product type_id, but I want to show it like on home page product (like widged product list), is there a way for it?

Comment: ....If answer is useful then you can approve answer....so other people can use that answer to solver their questions